# Let MySQL client command line accept characters with accents as input

Tags: mysql, editline

I don't know how to enable my MySQL client to accept letters with accents as input on the command line on Ubuntu. These chars are not echoed on the console nor accepted as input. As far as I remember, in previous versions of mysql, I solved this problem by launching the client with command `mysql --default-character-set=utf8` but this doesn't work with **mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper** on Ubuntu 18.04.

What does work is `echo 'SELECT "é" AS letter' | mysql <dbname>`, which gives the correct output.

I suspect the EditLine wrapper to be guilty of this behaviour, but I don't know how to get rid of this unwanted feature.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and the contents of `my.cnf`.

Comment: Please provide an example of the problem -- what you typed and what showed.

Comment: When I type "abcdé" at the command line interface of mysql, only the letters "abcd" show up and are sent to the MySQL client.

Comment: You can use mariadb-client. It supports utf-8 chars. Drop in replacement for mysql-client.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra: Thank you, I will try this. Can I use the maria-db client to connect a mysql server?

Comment: Yes. It is a drop in replacement of mysql, after all.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra: I can't install mariadb-client without uninstalling mysql, which is not possible in my case since I am in a production environment. Thanks anyway for the idea.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing phpmyadmin as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered today that I inherited in my current bash an alias from the setup of a previous installation:

```
alias mysql='mysql --default-character-set=utf8'
```

Since I removed that alias (with `unalias mysql`), the misbehaviour disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your database support UTF-8 encoding

Try the following : `ALTER DATABASE your_database_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: As far as I understand, the command you recommend affects the database and the server, but not the MySQL client. I issued it without any change at client side.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Terminal`,

```
Terminal > Preferences > Encodings > UTF-8 Unicode
```

Comment: This is not the answer, since I am able to type "é" at the shell within the terminal. It is only inside mysql that the letters with accents don't show up.

Comment: Let's see `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some row and column that is messed up.

Comment: the columns (inside the database on the server side) are not messed up. The chars with accents never reach the server. The command line of the mysql client just ignores these when typed at the prompt.

Comment: @PierreFrançois - OK.  That further implicates the terminal program.